# how do i give permission to some page in jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am new in jsf 2, I want to create a project with different roles,
each roles must be able to view its pages, for example some of pages is for admin user, and other users can not view these pages,
thanks.

Comment: The same as you would do with regular JSP/Servlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this example

http://www.simtay.com/part-2-securing-web-application-glassfish-v3-jaas-authentication-and-authorization/